# plot average line plot of a stacked bar plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a stacked bar chart of this nature done with Matplotlib in python:
[image]

Here is my working code:

```
df.resample("M")["ComName"].value_counts().unstack().rename(lambda  x: x.strftime("%b %Y")).plot(kind="bar", stacked=True, figsize=(20,20), color=color2)
```

How can I plot the a line plot of the average of each month on top of this plot

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like this:

```
s = df.resample("M")["ComName"].value_counts().unstack().rename(lambda x: x.strftime("%b %Y"))
ax = s.plot(kind="bar", stacked=True, figsize=(20,20), color=color2)
ax.plot(s.index, s.mean(1), linewidth=2.0)
```